# Ciclo do while en una calculadora (Java)

Tags: java, bucles, matemáticas

Me encuentro aprendiendo java y quería empezar por una calculadora sencilla en la que pudiera probar un poco de todo.
Quería añadirle un ciclo a mi calculadora para no tener que ejecutar el programa desde cero cada que se quiera hacer algo sin embargo me sale este error:

El error sale cuando se supone inicio el bucle de nuevo y elijo otra operación, sale con cualquiera de las 4
[image]

```java
   import java.util.*; 

   public class Calculator{

   public static void main(String[] args){

       int lop = 1;
       float x=0, y=0, z=0;
       String op=""; 
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

       do {
           System.out.println("what operation do you want to do?(sum, subtract, multiply, divide)");
           op = sc.nextLine();

           System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
           x = sc.nextFloat();
           y = sc.nextFloat();

           switch (op){
               case "sum":
                   z = x + y;
                   break;
               case "subtract":
                   z = x - y;
                   break;
               case "multiply":
                   z = x * y;
                   break;
               case "divide":
                   z = x / y;
                   break;
           }
           System.out.println("result of "+ op + ": "+ z);

           System.out.println("you want to try again?(enter the number)\n1.yes\n2.no");
           lop = sc.nextInt();

       }while(lop == 1);

       sc.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

moverla dentro del bloque do while, al inicio del bloque

```
do{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("what operation do you want to do?(sum, subtract, multiply, divide)");
    op = sc.nextLine();
```

Esto hará que el scanner se reinicie, limpiando efectivamente cualquier entrada pendiente en el buffer.

**EDITADO:**
Para que esto funcione, también debes quitar `sc.close()` al final del bucle.

Explicación: El enter al digitar 1 o 2 al final del bucle, es leido automáticamente en el scanner cuando solicitas nuevamente el operador con nextLine(); por lo cual debes reiniciar el scanner o limpiar el buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando hice lo que DEVX75 me dijo me salio este error:
[image: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651) at Calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:16)]

Sin embargo solucione mi problema poniendo "sc.nextLine()" depues del "lop = sc.nextInt();" para limpiar el buffer, osea quedaria asi:

```java
  import java.util.*; 

  public class Calculator{

  public static void main(String[] args){

      int lop = 1;
      float x=0, y=0, z=0;
      String op=""; 
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      do {
          System.out.println("what operation do you want to do?(sum, subtract, multiply, divide)");
          op = sc.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
          x = sc.nextFloat();
          y = sc.nextFloat();

          switch (op){
              case "sum":
                  z = x + y;
                  break;
              case "subtract":
                  z = x - y;
                  break;
              case "multiply":
                  z = x * y;
                  break;
              case "divide":
                  z = x / y;
                  break;
          }
          System.out.println("result of "+ op + ": "+ z);

          System.out.println("you want to try again?(enter the number)\n1.yes\n2.no");
          lop = sc.nextInt();
          sc.nextLine();

      }while(lop == 1);

      sc.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Si claro, no vi el sc.close();  al final del bucle.
Puedes prescindir de esa línea y mi solución debería funcionar. Mis disculpas.

Comment: Es verdad, si funciona si hago eso, si quieres puedes editar tu comentario diciendo que quite el sc.close(); y dejo tu respuesta como la correcta :3

Comment: Listo, agregado lo de quitar sc.close();